# Goblin apprentice mount, where to get it?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I just hit level 20 on my Goblin Mage. I trained apprentice riding in Orgimmar. I want to get the race specific mount and I'm not sure where/how to obtain it. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [Kall Worthaton](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=48510).  He's over in the goblin area in Org.  You'll want to go all the way to the south end of the goblin area.  Easiest way to find him is going to be to ask a guard for the First Aid trainer - Kall is about 20 feet to the right of that guy.